# Visual Studio 2013: native C++ single-step debugging (F10) slow

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging

I am using Visual Studio Premium 2013 Update 2 on a freshly installed (fast) machine with Windows 8.1 Update. Everything is running smoothly, only one thing bugs me:

**Problem**

When I debug a native C++ project (debug build) by going from line to line with F10 ("step over") it takes 1-2 seconds to go to the next line when I press the F10 key.

**What I tried**

I looked at several other questions related to slow debugging and made sure that neither of the following is not the reason in my case:

- Everything is local (app and all data), no network shares involved
- Disabling the Microsoft symbol server did not help
- I only have a single breakpoint
- Using the menu/toolbar instead of the keyboard does not make any difference

Answer (score 3):

In the default configuration "edit and continue" is enabled, but apparently not for native code:

[image]

When I disabled "edit and continue" completely, F10 stepping became much faster (0.5-1 s). The speed is tolerable now. I had to restart Visual Studio after I changed the configuration to this:

[image]